# Keycloak: 404 creating a role mapping for a user

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to use Keycloak's admin API in order to add a client-level role to the user role mapping. For this purpose **I'm using the admin endpoint :**

```
POST /{realm}/groups/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client}
```

**e.g.:**

```
http://localhost/tests/admin/realms/testrealm/users/d1a15b4c-9853-4d87-9b8d-d4cf3fac3650/role-mappings/clients/3f222762-5300-48f2-be48-32f001d5a7dc
```

**Request body as:**

```
[
    {
        "id": "32f02358-9312-4b7b-8584-85dcaf257667",
        "name": "test_role_app",
        "description": null,
        "scopeParamRequired": false
    }
]
```

The id in the body request, is the role ID.

**Keycloak is responding with error 404 with message:**

```
{
    "error": "Role not found"
}
```

Not sure what is the problem here as the role exists in the system. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Your example hits the user API not the groups API. Maybe you just got a wrong path?
Ref: /groups/ in query: /users/

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be that I was using the wrong roleId. I had two roles with same name (one at realm level and another one at client level). After using the correct ID everything worked well!

Additionally the whole request body looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "94cf6502-0375-4b62-a3ae-465d047738c3",
        "name": "test_role_app",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": true,
        "containerId": "a7e640cb-751d-4caa-81a0-79d38d31e025"
    }
]
```

Comment: This confuses me. Roles should be uniquely identifiable by their ID right? So, why add extra information such as `name`, `containerId`, `clientRole` and `composite`? What am I missing here?